# How to properly parse an iterator in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, parsing, iterator, openstreetmap, isnull

I have a huge OSM dataset with a lot of null-only columns which i want to get rid of.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    _column TEXT;
BEGIN
FOR _column  IN
    SELECT attname
    FROM pg_stats where tablename = 'rail_l' 
    and most_common_vals is null
    and most_common_freqs is null
    and histogram_bounds is null
    and correlation is null
    and null_frac = 1
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%',  _column;
    EXECUTE
    'ALTER TABLE rail_l DROP COLUMN ' || _column;
END LOOP;
END
$do$
```

Column names containing a colon cause the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
>   
> LINE 1: ALTER TABLE rail_l DROP COLUMN generator:source
>   
> QUERY:  ALTER TABLE rail_l DROP COLUMN generator:source
>   
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 16 at EXECUTE statement
>   
> SQL state: 42601

Perhaps a beginner's question since I used postgresql only for simple queries so far but i'd thankfully take any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) with the specifier `%I`:

```
...
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%',  _column;
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE rail_l DROP COLUMN %I', _column);
END LOOP;
...
```